# Is it necessary to host apps on a different domain?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, authentication, administration, configuration

I am starting with app development on SharePoint 2013 onprem. I want to develop Hight trust provider-hosted apps for my office catalog. After going through some msdn articles ([on-premises development environment for apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179923.aspx) and [using certificates in high-trust apps for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945118.aspx)), I figured out that apps need an isolated domain. But we are starting with a test environment. Is it necessary to have different domain and an isolated machine? In test environment, can't a single machine be used as SharePoint Server + Db Server + App Server? If yes, How can it be done? How apps would get authenticated in that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The domain that needs to be isolated is only a DNS domain not a new AD domain.

This is purely such that you have a separate IIS site where Cross Site Scripting is prevented by the browser.

You can add that new domain in DNS (see [Configure an environment for apps for SharePoint (SharePoint 2013)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx)) or hosts file.

The High trust app still needs the same certificate setup and needs to authenticate the users against the same provider as SharePoint.

CriticalPath has a good setup guide in their [members section](http://www.criticalpathtraining.com/members/) (require sign in) which goes through all the setup.